# Can we include an .so file LD_PRELOAD inside a file?

Tags: shared-objects, ld-preload

i have a file which is compiled and probably written in C. that file requires an *.so* file ( library file ).
The C Compiled file name is `/usr/local/solar/excusekey` and the *.so* library file is `/usr/local/libsolar/libexcuse.so`
When i remove `/usr/local/libsolar/libexcuse.so` and then i run `/usr/local/solar/excusekey` then it shows an error :

```
ERROR : ld.so object '/usr/local/libsolar/libexcuse.so' from 
LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
```

but when i run unset `LD_PRELOAD` and again run `/usr/local/solar/excusekey` then it shows the same error.

Does `/usr/local/solar/excusekey` loads that *libexcuse.so* library in it's C code ? or there is another trick or method of it?

Answer (score 0):

> Does /usr/local/solar/excusekey loads that libexcuse.so library in it's C code ?

Without knowing anything about `excusekey`, we can't tell.

It's possible to write an application which checks whether `LD_PRELOAD` contains desired library, an if not, set `LD_PRELOAD` and re-`exec` itself.

Whether or not that's what's happening here is anyone's guess.

Running the application under `strace -s1024 -fve execve excusekey` may provide clues to what the application is doing.